# What's a formal way to say something is "happening"?

Tags: synonyms, formality

What is a formal way to say something has a lot of activity in it? I can only think of two informal ways to say it. For example:

1. This field of physics is very "happening" right now.
2. This field of physics is very "hot" right now

Comment: Popular, trendy, in vogue . . .

Comment: You could say it's *very much a live issue* - which is slightly colloquial, but much less "slangy" than your examples. Or ***topical***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds as if the word you need is ***active***. *This field of physics is very active, right now*.

Answer (score 1):

I think [dynamic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Dynamic)  may fit in your context:

> - Characterized by continuous change, activity, or progress: a dynamic housing market.

or

[In full swing or in high gear](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+full+swing): may be useful expression to convey the idea

> - Fig. at the peak of activity; moving fast or efficiently. (*Typically: be ~; move [into] ~; get [into] ~.) In the summer months, things really get into full swing around here. We go skiing in the mountains each winter. Things are in high gear there in November.

Comment: "Dynamic" and "in full swing" are perfect fits.